# NodeJS: Listening for a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this app where I need to listen for a change in a variable called `qrstate`.

```
var qrstate = ""

app.get('/getqrstate', function (req, res) {    
  if (qrstate != "") {
    res.jsonp({
      status: 'success',
      msg: 'kiosk state is found',
    })
  }
})

app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {
  qrstate = req.query.state
}
```

The user will first visit the frontend page with QR code and this will call /getqrstate. The user will scan the QR code with his handphone app. After scanning, the handphone app will call another server from the provider and the provider's server will make a callback to my backend server's `/callback` with a state code.  It would then save to `qrstate` with `qrstate = req.query.state`

So if `qrstate` is not empty, I have like to send a response back to the frontend `client`/`browser` page.  How could I listen to this `qrstate`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you detail your requirement, especially how the behaviour shall be when there are hundreds of clients sending QR codes in parallel and hence hundreds of callbacks pending? Somehow you must relate each callback to an incoming request containing a QR code image.

Comment: each qrstate is actually used for distinguishing between the qrcode, so it is tracked.

Comment: Yes, how do you distinguish which qr state to return when someone calls `/getqrstate`?  What most people do in the scenario I think you're describing is store the qrstate in a database and when someone calls `getqrstate` look that information up in the DB, based on <criteria>

Comment: When someone visits the page with the QR code, /getqrstate will be called first.  The qr code is then scanned and another server will be called which in turn will call /callback, so /callback is actually called later.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, I have amended the question, you can take a look.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, I don't think the diagram is correct.

Comment: Then I have not yet understood what you want, sorry.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, I have amended my question again, I am sorry for the confusion.  Actually I only need to listen to changes to a variable in nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than change a variable, have an [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) as global variable. Then the `/getqrstate` handler can

```js
eventEmitter.on("qrstateDetermined", function(qrstate) {
  res.jsonp(...);
});
```

and the `/callback` handler can

```js
eventEmitter.emit("qrstateDetermined", req.query.state);
```

However, *one* global variable will not be sufficient, because every incoming `/getqrstate` request must be mapped to its own event emitter, and the *corresponding* `/callback` request be mapped to the same event emitter.

Comment: I was trying out this nodejs package https://github.com/sindresorhus/on-change and it seems to work, I will try out EventEmitter tmr